# Angular 5 works with ng serve but breaks during maven install

Tags: java, angular, maven, karma-jasmine, hadoop-yarn

The application works fine when running Ng serve but when I run a maven install that runs my build, I get the following **error**.

```
'app-comparisons' is not a known element:
[INFO]  1. If 'app-comparisons' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
[INFO]  2. If 'app-comparisons' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
[INFO]                      </table>
[INFO]                  </div>
[INFO]                [ERROR ->]<app-comparisons></app-comparisons>
[INFO]              </div>
[INFO]              <div id="goals-2" class="spot-tabs__content">
```

My selector is the same in my html as in my component.ts

Here's is the component, **comparisons.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ComparisonsService} from '../services/comparisons.service';
import {Region} from '../models/region';
import {VetCount} from '../models/vetcount';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comparisons',
  templateUrl: './comparisons.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comparisons.component.scss']
})
    export class ComparisonsComponent implements OnInit {
    regions: Region [];
    vetcounts: VetCount [];
    similarCount = 245;
    constructor(private comparisonsService: ComparisonsService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
      this.getRegions();
      this.getVetCounts();
    }
    getRegions(): void {
    this.regions = this.comparisonsService.getRegions();
    }
    getVetCounts(): void {
    this.vetcounts = this.comparisonsService.getVetCounts();
    }
}
```

And finally here is my **app.module.ts** which has my component imported and declared. I am not sure what I am missing.

```
import { ComparisonsComponent } from './comparisons/comparisons.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    VdcComponent,
    PracticeComponent,
    IconComponent,
    ComparisonsComponent,
    GoalsComponent,
    ReportsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    routing,
    ChartsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuardService,
    AuthenticationService,
    DataRequestService,
    ComparisonsService,
    ReportsService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Again the application works fine locally running ng serve but soon as it do a mvn install and it starts running Yarn and karma test it breaks with that error.

Comment: What do you get if you run "ng test"?

Comment: PhantomJs 2.1.1 (windows 7 0.0.0) : Executed 15 of 15 (3 failed) also its saying NullInjectorError : No Provider for ReportsService.  I have a Service called ReportService and it is added to the app.module.ts

Comment: I think you might want to fix those 3 failed unit test first before doing the maven install.